# How to backup stored procedure backup from Google Cloud SQL?

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, phpmyadmin, google-cloud-sql

I want to create/export only the stored procedures from my Google Cloud SQL DB. I tried several commands on my phpmyadmin(installed on Google App Engine) console but I am consistently facing the error mentioned below.

List of commands I've tried:

```
1. mysqldump --routines=true -u root sarda_yogi_mobile > my_database.sql
2. mysqldump --databases database_name [-h instance-ip -u username -p password] \ --hex-blob --default-character-set=utf8 > database_file.sql
3. mysqldump --databases database_name [-h instance-ip -u username -p password] --default-character-set=utf8 > database_file.sql
4. mysqldump --host="127.0.0.1" --user="root" --password="" --routines --triggers --events dbname > my_file.sql
```

Error Message:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysqldump --routines=true -u root db_name > my_database.sql' at line 1
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thank You :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Vadim said, you're attempting command-line statements at a SQL shell, which (as you've seen) doesn't work.

To perform a stored procedure export from within phpMyAdmin, go to the "Routines" tab of your database and click "Export" for the routine you wish to export. You could instead use the checkboxes to select several to export at once, if you prefer.

[image: Routines dialog]

Comment: Which phpmyadmin version you're using? The one I'm using is 4.3.11 and it is not showing the checkboxes. Because of this I have to export each stored procedure one by one, consumes a lot of time

Comment: Looks like that functionality was introduced with version 4.5.0, so you could upgrade to the latest available release to get this functionality.

Comment: @IsacccBennetch thanks for the help..let me upgrade the version of phpmyadmin & see if it works for me. Hoping you will hear a good news from me next time :)

Answer (score 1):

Those are commands you need to run on a command line, not via the phpMyAdmin shell.

If you want to perform an export from phpMyAdmin, there are some guides available on the web, e.g. http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/phpmyadmin/export-database-using-phpmyadmin

Comment: But I only want to export stored procedures, is there any way to achieve it.